# How to get related model count with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables users and transactions. users table:

```
 id     name
------------- 
 1       joe
 2       jane
 3       phil
```

and transactions table :

```
id   user_id   is_successful  
------------------------------
1      1            0
2      1            1
3      1            1
4      2            0
5      3            1
6      3            0
```

I want to get all successfull transactions count by each user. something like this:

```
joe =>2,
jane=>0,
phil=>1
```

I tried something like the following but it gets only successful transactions:

```
Transaction::wherIsSuccessful(1)
->with('user')
->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(*) as transaction_counts'))
->groupBy('user_id');
```

Comment: What do you mean with active transaction, do you mean `is_successful` is 1 ? cause there're a condition already for it `wherIsSuccessfull(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withCount` method ([more details](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)) to get user's successful transaction count.

```
User::withCount(['transactions' => function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('is_successful', true);
}])->get();
```